# Disable Alt Tab MRU

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, application-switcher

How to disable MRU (Most Recently Used) in <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and instead use regular cycling (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Chrome). I've looked in tweaks and dconf editor. I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.