# Stop rearrangement of windows on Alt+Tab

Tags: application-switcher

I expect Alt+Tab and Shift+Alt+Tab to cycle through all open applications in a workplace in order or in reverse order, even after I switch applications (like in Windows), but that's not the default behavior.

Here's what I mean:
Given applications A, B, C in that order, A is in focus.

**The behavior I want**

- I use Alt+Tab to switch focus to application B.
- The order of applications remains A, B, C.
- I use Shift+Alt+Tab to switch focus back to application A.

**The current behavior, which I find counter-intuitive**

- I use Alt+Tab to switch focus to application B.
- The order of applications swaps between A and B. The order is now B,
  A, C.
- I use Shift+Alt+Tab thinking I'll switch back to application A but instead I find application C.

Is there an extension or Gnome setting that'll allow for the behavior I want, or is this hard-coded?

Comment: [Same question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1176638/480481), unfortunately no solution yet, seems hard-coded.